# PHP file upload not working - Unable to move

Tags: php, file-upload

HTML

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' name='uphoto' id='uphoto' accept='image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg' >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Changes">
```

PHP (profile.php)

```
    $target_dir = '/images/demo/profiles/';
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['uphoto']['name']);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


    if (!empty($_FILES['uphoto']['name'])) {
        //echo 'A file was selected for upload';

        // check file size
        if ($_FILES['uphoto']['size'] > 5000000) {
            echo '<p style="color:red">Sorry, the photo must be smaller than 5MB.</p>';
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo '<p style="color:red">Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</p>';
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo '<p style="color:red">Sorry, your file was not uploaded.</p>';
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uphoto']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
                echo '<p style="color:green">The file '. basename( $_FILES['uphoto']['name']). ' has been uploaded.</p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p style="color:red">Sorry, there was an error uploading your file:'.var_dump($_FILES['uphoto']['error']).'</p>';
            }
        }
    }
```

ERROR VAR DUMP

```
int(0)
```

ERROR LOG

> PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(/images/demo/profiles/Blue hills.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /hermes/bosoraweb103/b1029/ipg.domain/sd/profile.php on line 182 
>   PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpLeRQSS' to
>   '/images/demo/profiles/Blue hills.jpg' in
>   /hermes/bosoraweb103/b1029/ipg.domain/sd/profile.ph

The form is actually more complex and all of it work except the file upload. I just trimmed it to make it easy to read. I contacted the wed host (iPage) concerning the issue, but they are saying their server is working fine and the file limit is way big.

Comment: Probably relative path issue. Check `$target_file` path with respect to *profile.php*

Answer (score 0):

```
 $target_dir = './images/demo/profiles/';
```

instead of

```
 $target_dir = '/images/demo/profiles/';
```